# Can I use Entity Framework 6 (not core) in .net core?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, spatial-data

Entity Framework Core does not support spatial data, which I need to use in my app.

Can I use Entity Framework 6 in .net core? If so, how can I register `DatabaseContext` in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Yes, EF6 has been cross-platform since version 6.3. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef-core-3-0-and-ef-6-3-general-availability/#what-s-new-in-ef-6-3

**ORIGINAL ANSWER THAT IS NOW INVALID**: No, you can not directly, because EF6 doesn't support .NET Core.
But, you can create another project, that compiles against full .NET framework and use it as a reference.

MS has actually made a decent tutorial for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-asp-net-core-project

Comment: Can I use EF 6 DB first with asp.net core

Comment: If we do this, can we deploy the solution on a linux server ?

Comment: @Terai, no. From Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.2), under Overview section:   To use Entity Framework 6, your project has to compile against .NET Framework, as Entity Framework 6 doesn't support .NET Core. If you need cross-platform features you will need to upgrade to Entity Framework Core.

Comment: That Microsoft Document is utter rubbish. Spent hours trying to get it working but end of day the `Syste.Data.SqlClient` breaks everything in Core. The best interim solution is using `Z.EntityFramework.Classic.Community` (as per answers below) and then waiting for Core 3.0 and come back to EF6 ... if you need to. I dont think this should be the accepted answer.. anymore. But I dont want to downvote either.. please consider the other options.

Comment: Why is "Original answer no longer valid" ? Surely we can still create another project, that compiles against full .NET framework and use it as a reference. Then target Dotnet Core to run on full .NET Framework.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, "Original answer no longer valid" starting with .NET 3.0 and above. See here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/324

Answer (score 39):

#### Update

You can now use EF 6.3 with .NET Core 3.0:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef-core-3-0-and-ef-6-3-general-availability/#what-s-new-in-ef-6-3

Below is an excerpt. However, EF Core has come a long way these days and it's worth giving it another go before going back to something that's reaching end-of-life soon. Specifically for your issue, [EF Core supports mapping to spatial data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) using the [NetTopologySuite spatial library](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) since version 2.2.

> ### What’s new in EF 6.3
>
> - Support for .NET Core 3.0
> - The EntityFramework package now targets .NET Standard 2.1 in addition to .NET Framework 4.x.
> - This means that EF 6.3 is cross-platform and supported on other operating systems besides Windows, like Linux and macOS.
> - The migrations commands have been rewritten to execute out of process and work with SDK-style projects.
> - Support for SQL Server HierarchyId.
> - Improved compatibility with Roslyn and NuGet PackageReference.
> - Added ef6.exe utility for enabling, adding, scripting, and applying migrations from assemblies. This replaces migrate.exe.
>   There are certain limitations when using EF 6.3 in .NET Core. For example:
> - Data providers need to be also ported to .NET Core. We only ported the SQL Server provider, which is included in the EF 6.3 package.
> - Spatial support won’t be enabled with SQL Server because the spatial types aren’t enabled to work with .NET Core.
> - Note that this limitation applies to EF 6.3 but not to EF Core 3.0. The latter continues to support spatial using the NetTopologySuite
>   library.
> - There’s currently no support for using the EF designer directly on .NET Core or .NET Standard projects.

#### Original Answer

It isn’t ready yet, but starting with .NET Core 3.0, you will be able to.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

> Similarly, EF6 will be updated to work on .NET Core 3.0, to provide a simple path forward for existing applications using EF6.

https://youtu.be/GN54OV5cCBM?t=1146

> But there's also EF6, which we've already announced is going to be ported to work on .NET Core...

Comment: You can already download a preview version: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-6-3-preview-with-net-core-support/

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE:** Yes, EF6 has been cross-platform since version 6.3. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef-core-3-0-and-ef-6-3-general-availability/#what-s-new-in-ef-6-3

**ORIGINAL ANSWER THAT IS NOW INVALID:** Like @Niko said, you cannot directly with `EF6` but there is a fork that allows it.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Classic](https://entityframework-classic.net/)

Entity Framework Classic is an EF6 fork. It's everything you like about EF6, but with better performance, must-have features, .NET Core support, and more.

There is a **FREE Community** version that includes pretty much everything and an Enterprise version that include additional features.

Comment: Quite literally a drop in replacement.. Uninstall EF6, Install `Z.EntityFramework.Classic.Community` - If you getting `Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type` Make sure to install the same package in your root app, say AWS Lambda, Azure Function, Core Console app...

Comment: https://entityframeworkcore.com/providers-oracle seems to be very outdated?

Comment: I just added this to my project and it worked straight out of the box. Great work guys!

Comment: What about EDMX designer?

Comment: Why is "Original answer no longer valid" ? Surely we can still create another project, that compiles against full .NET framework and use it as a reference. Then target Dotnet Core to run on full .NET Framework.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, "Original answer no longer valid" starting with .NET 3.0 and above. See here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/324